# Enabling 2-way (client-authenticated) SSL in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

We have a node.js/express.js application that is currently using only 1-way (server-authenticated) SSL, and is working fine, but now, I am trying to enable it to use 2-way/client-authenticated SSL, but I am having problems doing this (node version is 8.5.0).

Here's the initial part of the current app, that sets up the SSL server:

```
if (sslListen) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');
    // Setup HTTPS
    var options = {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(SECURITY_DIR + 'server.pfx'),
        passphrase: xxxxx
    };

    logger.log("++++++++ Listen SSL Mode ++++++++");
    var secureServer = https.createServer(options, app)
        .listen(listenPort);
} else {
    logger.log("++++++++ Listen NON-SSL Mode ++++++++");
    app.listen(listenPort, function () {
        logger.log("\n\n2-" + BANNER + "-2\n\n");
    });
}
```

We have a test URI at "/", and when I hit that using Firefox, I get a correct (dummy) response message.

So I added a "requestCert" to the options:

```
if (sslListen) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');
    // Setup HTTPS
    var options = {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(SECURITY_DIR + 'server.pfx'),
        passphrase: xxxxx,
        requestCert: true
    };

    logger.log("++++++++ Listen SSL Mode ++++++++");
    var secureServer = https.createServer(options, app)
        .listen(listenPort);
} else {
    logger.log("++++++++ Listen NON-SSL Mode ++++++++");
    app.listen(listenPort, function () {
        logger.log("\n\n2-" + BANNER + "-2\n\n");
    });
}
```

and when I test with Firefox, I get to an error page:

"Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to XXXXXX.dev:4269. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters. Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT"

When I test, I am not seeing any output (error or otherwise) at the node side.

Can someone what might be the problem or how to diagnose it?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I was able to test the connection (and present a client cert) successfully.  I used openssl s_client to diagnose the problem and it was that I did not have a "ca" set in the node.js "options".