# Make client-certificate optional with Node SSL (rejectUnauthorized: true doesn't do it?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is is a followup to another thread that I have:

[Enabling 2-way (client-authenticated) SSL in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724050/enabling-2-way-client-authenticated-ssl-in-node-js/48725282#48725282)

So, now that I have the client-authentication/2-way SSL working, we want this app/port configured so that it functions both when a client cert is presented, and, optionally, when a client cert is not presented.  This is similar to would be similar to setting "sslVerifyClient optional" in an Apache httpd.conf/ssl.conf (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient).

I tried adding `rejectUnauthorized: true` explicitly to the `options` but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to do this (set the server port to accept either client cert or no client cert)?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: [rejectUnauthorized defaults to true; you need to set it to false](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, again :(...

Re-reading the rejectUnauthorized documentation, I realized that maybe setting it to 'false' instead of 'true' might do what I wanted, and I just tested, and that does work.

Jim